# Network Copy Paste

Tags: networking

Is there a easy way to share your clipboard over network. Basically I work on multiple machines simultaneously and constantly need to copy and paste between machines, is there a tool that can help me with this?

Comment: I think synergy does this. keyboard/mouse/clipboard sharing.

Comment: http://wonder-board.appspot.com/

Comment: I just use a .txt file on a network share... Doesn't require an Internet connection and is much more secure than sending your (possibly confidential) contents offsite...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I found this - http://wonder-board.appspot.com/ Seems to serve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Within a lan, and if all systems in question are running windows, [mouse without borders](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27589) would do this. With a hetrogenous network, [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) would do well.In both cases, its a KM sharing application that happens to share clipboards.

If its just text, I'd note that the use of [wall](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_wall.htm) for the purpose of sharing text snippets is gloriously hacky, and what i'd do in that particular usecase.

While the OP seems to have chosen a cloud based solution, it does seem a LITTLE overkill (and scary!) to send one's clipboard contents over the cloud between two systems right next to each other.